# Remove timezone jquery

Tags: jquery, datetime, datepicker

I use DateTime picker (tempusdominus-bootstrap-4) to get data from API, from date and time I pick in date time picker. But by default, i get time from -5 days from today.
Problem is timezone. 
here is my code

```
let date = new Date();
    console.log(date); //Fri May 11 2018 08:34:43 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 5); //my 'from' date is default -5, but i can pick another date if want
    let dateString = date.toISOString().split(".")[0];
    let eventsFrom = dateString; //here is my formated date and time in format i need
    console.log(eventsFrom); // 2018-05-06T06:34:43
    let dateToday = new Date();
    let eventsTo = dateToday.toISOString().split(".")[0];
```

Problem is, getted time is allways 2h less... 
If i pick time 10:00 h output is 8:00 h.

How to remove or disable timezone?

```js
        let date = new Date();
        console.log(date);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 5);
        let dateString = date.toISOString().split(".")[0];
        let eventsFrom = dateString;
        console.log(eventsFrom);
        let dateToday = new Date();
        let eventsTo = dateToday.toISOString().split(".")[0];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What result do you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: If i pick 8:00h i want to get 8:00h, but i get 6:00h. In my code you can see `let eventsFrom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.toISOString` serialize date as UTC datetime.
You can use `Date.toLocaleString()` to get locale time, you can also serialize it manually.

```js
let date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 5);
let dateString = date.toLocaleString();
let eventsFrom = dateString;
console.log(eventsFrom);
let dateToday = new Date();
let eventsTo = dateToday.toLocaleString();
console.log(eventsTo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i fix this with `moment(dateString).format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");` @vp_arth pls add this in your answer. Thnx